# Key error: 0 with dataframe filtered from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe filtered from another dataframe. They have obviously the same columns and values but when I apply a loop to the filtered one, I've get a Key error: 0 while in the original one it's no problem.
Here is the two dataframes:

The original one is this:

```
          ISIN         ISSUE DATE    MATURITY       PRICE   
     0  AR121489 Corp  29/03/2019    29/09/2019    97.314000
     1  AR714081 Corp  29/06/2019    29/12/2019    97.014500
     2  AT452141 Corp  29/12/2019    29/06/2020    92.959000
     3  QJ100923 Corp  29/03/2020    29/09/2020    96.696222
```

With this one read it from a CSV, I transform the data to filter it:

```
df['ISSUE DATE mod'] = df['ISSUE DATE'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%m/%Y'))
df['MATURITY mod'] = df['MATURITY'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%m/%Y'))
df['ISSUE DATE mod'] = df['ISSUE DATE mod'].astype('datetime64[ns]').copy()
df['MATURITY mod'] =df['MATURITY mod'].astype('datetime64[ns]').copy()
```

And then I filter the dataframe to obtain this one:

```
fval = dt.date(2019,7,29)
np.datetime64(fecha_valoracion)
df2= df.loc[(tabla_info_bonos['ISSUE DATE mod'] < fval) & (df['MATURITY mod'] > fval)]
```

And I get this dataframe:

```
     ISIN         ISSUE DATE  MATURITY     ISSUE DATE mod   MATURITY mod
0  AR121489 Corp  29/03/2019  29/09/2019     2019-03-29        2019-09-29
1  AR714081 Corp  29/06/2019  29/12/2019     2019-06-29        2019-12-29
```

Then, if I do the following operation to the original dataframe it works, but no with the filtered one:

```
maturity = []
for i in range(len(df2['MATURITY'])):
    maturities = pd.to_datetime(df2['MATURITY'][i]).date()
    maturity.append(maturities)
OUTPUT = KeyError: 0
```

I suspect that the problem is in the filtering part, but I don't know how to fix it.
Any help with this will be perfect and I will be very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that there is a problem with your for loop at the end

```
maturity = []
for i in range(len(df2['MATURITY'])):
    maturities = pd.to_datetime(df2['MATURITY'][i]).date()
    maturity.append(maturities)
```

instead of the above code, could you please try something like like below

```
maturity = []
for item in df2['MATURITY']:
    maturity.append(pd.to_datetime(item).date())
```

or you can use list comprehension as well

```
maturity = [pd.to_datetime(item).date()for item in df2['MATURITY']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works with that. Thank you for taking your time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Reset the index of the dataframe. Filtered dataframe has index corresponding to the one in orginal dataframe.

df2 = df2.reset_index(drop= True)

Comment: Thank you so much, this one also works but I just can give one answer as correct, but really, thank you for taking your time to answer @Rauf Bhat